# Equation of two variables with no solutions in a given countable set

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, geometry

Let $(x_{n})$ be a sequence of non-negative real numbers diverging to infinity. Can we find a real number $r\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x_{n}-x_{m}\neq r$ for all $n,m\in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Ummm... *sure*.  Let $x_n$ be the integers, and $r = \sqrt{e}$.

Comment: There is no restrictions on the sequence $(x_{n})$.

Comment: Not what you said.  You wrote "Let $(x_n)$ be *a* sequence of non-negative..."

Comment: I didn't say it is a sequence of natural numbers.

Comment: No... you said it was a sequence of non-negative real numbers diverging to infinity.  That's precisely what I gave an example of.

Comment: If you had said "Let $a$ be a number..." and I said "OK, let $a = 7.3$," you cannot return and say "Oh... but that's not the number I had in mind."  (Frankly, I'm guessing you're not a native English speaker and don't see your language error here.)

Comment: I am not a native English speaker, and, frankly, I am guessing you are not a mathematician. As you don't see that the question is asking to find a real number $r$ such that $x_{n}-x_{m}\neq r$ without imposing any additional conditions such as the sequence is the integers!

Comment: I have a PhD in Physics and have held professorships in Mathematics, Statistics, and Computer Science Departments in elite US universities.  If your question is the *reverse* (as you're now trying to state), then you should have stated that instead.  I urge you (again) to work side-by-side with a native English speaker to see your error.

Comment: I urge you to have a look at @Dave's answer.

Comment: Just to see your mathematical error, $0$ and $\sqrt{e}$ could be terms of the given sequence $(x_n)$.

Comment: Huh???  "... *the* given sequence"??  *Which* sequence did you "give"?  I see none.  For any one you "give," I can find an $r$ that cannot be expressed as a difference... but that's different.  (Again... talk to a native English speaker who will help you see your errors.). Yes, Dave expresses this fact clearly.

Comment: Okay great Mathematician and PhD holder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$ is countable, so certainly there are countably many differences $x_n-x_m$. However, there are uncountably many $r\in\mathbb R$.

Answer (score -2):

I guess the question was rather : can we find a sequence $(x_n)$ of positive numbers that diverge to $+\infty$ such that for all $r\in \mathbb{R}^+$, there exists $n,m$ such that $u_n -u_m = r$.

The answer is **no**.

In fact, $\{u_n - u_m; n,m\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is countable, while $\mathbb{R}$ is not.

Comment: what is wrong with my answer?

Comment: It answers your question, not my question.

Comment: it's actually the same, just said an other way (more explicit I think), and by the way I use the same argument as @Dave)

Comment: Should I delete my answer?